# Python write object properties to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, oop

I am solving a [n-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation) simulation problem using Python OOP. Each of my particles is an object with properties such as mass, position, velocity, etc, and I would like to every few simulation time write particle's properties to a file. So, each particle would have a file, and each line would have its properties in a particular time. So for instance, my class would be something like,

```
from numpy import mod

class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = 3        # particle id
        self.t = 0.7        # s
        self.mass = 20.     # kg
        self.x = 20.        # m
        self.y = 30.        # m
        self.dt2store = 0.7 # s (simulated time)

    def store(self):
        if mod(self.t, self.dt2store):
            self.writer()

    def writer(self):
        '''
        It stores data in particle id3 file
        data2store = [self.t, self.mass, self.x, self.y]
        '''
```

What is the best, more efficient way of doing such?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In python, there is a library called [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) that allows you to
serialize or de-serialize objects. It is not very efficient when compared with other libraries such as JSON and raises some security issue (you can check it [here](https://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/)). But it provides an easy way to write and load objects with the methods:

- `pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)`
- `pickle.load(file, *, fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII", errors="strict")`

Another alternative would be to use the [JSON library methods](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#basic-usage):

- `json.dump`
- `json.load`

But in this case, you would have to transform your object into some built-in data type that the JSON library accepts like `dict`, `list` or `tuple` and in case you need the object when you load it, you would have to recreate it. Something like this:

```py
with open('particle1.json', 'w') as fp:
  json.dump({'idx': particle.idx, 't': particle.t }, fp)

particle = Particle()
with open('particle1.json', 'r') as fp:
  particle_properties = json.load(fp)
  particle.idx = particle_properties['idx']
  particle.t = particle_properties['t']
```